# nsupdate not working with an input file

Tags: dns, bind

On my debian testing server when i run the nsupdate command and enter the details manually, everything works as it should. For example:

```
nsupdate -k /etc/bind/update.key
> update add PC1.direct.labo 3600 A 192.168.100.1
> send
> quit
```

After that, I find the record in my zone file.
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q7yg.png)

The problem comes when I try to use an input file, let's call it "order.dns" :

```
update add PC2.direct.labo 3600 A 192.168.100.2
show
send
quit
```

and execute it with:

```
nsupdate order.dns -k /etc/bind/update.key
```

then i get `update failed: REFUSED`

[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUgvV.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nsupdate uses BSD-style option parsing, where all options must be specified strictly *before* non-option (i.e. positional) arguments, like this:

```
nsupdate -k /etc/bind/update.key order.dns
```

In your case, the `-k` that's specified *after* the filename is not interpreted as an option but becomes another positional argument together with `order.dns` (and so does the key filename).

If this were a program that accepted multiple files, you'd get an error message along the lines of "`File '-k' not found`":

```
$ uname
NetBSD
$ cat -n test
     1  Line one
     2  Line two
     3  Line three
$ cat test -n
Line one
Line two
Line three
cat: -n: No such file or directory
$
```

But since nsupdate only takes one filename, the additional positional arguments remain ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanks to this capability of nsupdate I think I can combine this command with an interactive script that collects the user's entries in a single file, and at his choice to add or delete them from the zone file.